# "<Long> a proponent of government health insurance, he pointed out that millions of Americans have no health insurance at all."

Tags: meaning-in-context, parts-of-speech, parsing, appositives, functions

[cambridge.org](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/proponent):
**(1)** ***Long** a proponent of government health insurance, he pointed out that millions of Americans have no health insurance at all*.
I can't understand the grammar of using "*long*" here.

my variant without "*long*":
**(2)** *A proponent of government health insurance, he pointed out that millions of Americans have no health insurance at all*.
As far as I understand, the noun phrase "*a proponent of government health insurance*" in (2) is the appositive to the pronoun "*he*".
But I can't understand why to add "*long*" at the beginning is grammatically correct.

Tell me please:
Is "*long*" in (1) an adverb? If not, then what part of speech is it?
What does "*long*" in (1) function as?
Is the noun phrase "*a proponent of government health insurance*" in (1) the appositive to the pronoun "*he*" just as in (2)?

Comment: Compare to “Clearly a forgery, the painting has little value.”

Comment: This may help you: "A *longtime* proponent of government health insurance, he pointed out ..."

Comment: Or "[Since he was for] long a proponent of government health insurance, he pointed out"

Comment: You are correct that **long** is an **adverb**. It modifies a form of the linking verb "to be" which is *elided* from the sentence. If you add the implicit verb back in, you'd get "Having **long** been a proponent of government health insurance, he pointed out..." Here it's clear that "long" modifies "having been."

Comment: For your second question *Is the noun phrase "a proponent of government health insurance" in (1) the appositive to the pronoun "he" just as in (2)* - that's a great question! I don't actually know for sure, but it seems like if there is an implicit form of "to be" that the noun phrase in (1) would actually be a **predicate noun** instead of an appositive like in (2).

Answer (score 1):

"Long" modifies the phrase "a proponent of government health insurance," specifically the verb within the phrase which is implied ("has been"). (I.e., "he has been a proponent" vs. "he has long been a proponent.")

**"Long" is an adverb.** It indicates the duration of time for which the person has been a proponent of government health insurance, that the person's advocacy is not new but has been consistent over an extended period, unlike the sentence modified without the word "long."

I believe the noun phrase "a proponent of government health insurance" still serves as an appositive to the pronoun "he," just as it does in sentence 2, in which "long" serves as an adverb modifying that appositive phrase, without changing the phrase's relationship to the word "he."

Comment: And you can see long is an adverb because you could substitute other adverbs like frequently, commonly, etc.